# What is meaning of timestamp in perf?

Tags: linux, timestamp, perf

I'd like to use 'perf' to measure real execution time of a function. 'perf script' command gives timestamp when the function is called.

```
Xorg  1523 [001] 25712.423702:    probe:sock_write_iter: (ffffffff95cd8b80)
```

The timestamp field's format is `X.Y`. How can I understand this value? Is it X.Y seconds?

Comment: Timestamps "X.Y" in perf output are X seconds and Y microseconds. In `perf script` output it probably X seconds since linux boot. Similar time format is used in `dmesg` output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`X.Y` is the timestamp in units of `seconds.microseconds`.

How this value is displayed can be looked at [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.7/source/tools/perf/builtin-script.c#L716). You can pass the switch `--ns` to `perf script` to display the timestamps in `seconds.nanoseconds` format too.

To understand this value, you need to understand how the `perf` module calculates timestamps. You can associate each event with a different clock function to compute the timestamps. By default, `perf` uses `sched_clock` function to compute timestamps for an event, more details [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.7/source/kernel/events/core.c#L10731).

```
event->clock = &local_clock;
```

But you can use the `-k` switch along with `perf record` command to associate an event with various clockids.

```
-k, --clockid
           Sets the clock id to use for the various time fields in the
           perf_event_type records. See clock_gettime(). In particular
           CLOCK_MONOTONIC and CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW are supported, some
           events might also allow CLOCK_BOOTTIME, CLOCK_REALTIME and
           CLOCK_TAI.
```

Adding the `-k` switch to `perf record` command will enable various clock functions depending on which clockid you use, as can be seen [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.7/source/kernel/events/core.c#L11070).

`sched_clock` function shall return the number of nanoseconds since the system was started. A particular architecture may or may not provide an implementation of `sched_clock()` on its own. The system jiffy counter will be used as `sched_clock()`, if a local implementation is not provided.

Note that, all of the above code snippets are for **Linux kernel 5.6.7**.

Comment: It's `sched_clock_cpu()` instead of `sched_clock()` if `CONFIG_HAVE_UNSTABLE_SCHED_CLOCK = y`. Try `perf trace -T -- head /proc/sched_debug` to get the difference between the two clocks. The diff is expect to be `journalctl -k |grep -m1 "Marking stable" | awk '{print $NF}'` ns.

Answer (score -1):

X.Y is the raw format of the date. The perf's time function, which operates in nanoseconds, needs to be converted to a human readable format. Use this website to convert it to date, http://www.timestamp.fr/ , or using bash

```
date -d @25712
```