# perf- how to get the current runtime clock of the program

Tags: c++, c, linux, timestamp, perf

I'm using perf tools to measure performance
with the commands:

```
perf record -F 99 -T -d -p $(pid_of_my_program) 
perf sched script -v
```

and the result I got:

```
TimerTask 23652 544157.760762:          1 cycles:          c0044606 finish_task_switch ([kernel.kallsyms])
       TimerTask 23652 544157.760788:          1 cycles:          c0044606 finish_task_switch ([kernel.kallsyms])
       TimerTask 23652 544157.760797:          1 cycles:          c0044606 finish_task_switch ([kernel.kallsyms])
       TimerTask 23652 544157.760804:         52 cycles:          c0044606 finish_task_switch ([kernel.kallsyms])
       TimerTask 23652 544157.760811:       5162 cycles:          c0044606 finish_task_switch ([kernel.kallsyms])
```

I tried to convert the timestamp:

```
date -d @544157.760762
```

and I got Unix time:

```
Wed Jan  7 09:09:17 IST 1970
```

How can I set the clock to the current time?
i want to get the current runtime of the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that you want to get the **current timestamp** at which the `perf` samples were recorded, and thus the times when the process tracked by `perf` was running.

The `perf` module uses `sched_clock` function to compute timestamps for an event. The timestamp that you see in the `perf sched script` command is actually representing the number of nanoseconds (formatted as `seconds.nanoseconds`) since the system was started. That is what `sched_clock` computes. More details in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61428513) answer.

Just converting the timestamp here, will not give you the current time at which the sample was collected.

To obtain the current time, you can do something like this-

```
#! /bin/bash

# get uptime in yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS format
uptime_since=$(uptime -s)         

# convert uptime to epoch
epoch_uptime=`date --date="$uptime_since" +"%s%N"`

# add the timestamp obtained from perf to the previous result
current_time_in_epoch=$((epoch_uptime + 544157760762000))

# convert the nanosecond epoch+perf time to seconds
current_time_in_seconds=$((current_time_in_epoch/1000000000))

# convert this to timestamp format
current_time=`date -d @$current_time_in_seconds`

echo $current_time
```

All the above commands take into account that the shell you use is `bash`.